# How to get 'type' field descriptor from ctypes Structure or Union field

Tags: python, types, ctypes, descriptor

I have a structure with different datatype fields. I would like to iterate through the structure fields, check the datatype, and set the field with an appropriate value.

I have access to the size and offset of the field through the .size and .offset attribute of the field. How can I get the 'type' attribute of the field? Using *type(value)* does not print the ctypes datatype for the particular field. If I *print value* then I do see the ctypes datatype but there doesn't seem to be an attribute to access this directly.

How can I access the type field descriptor directly?

```
from ctypes import *

class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("one", c_long),
                ("two", c_char),
                ("three", c_byte)]

>>> A.one
<Field type=c_long, ofs=0, size=4>
>>> A.one.offset
0
>>> A.one.size
4
>>> type(A.one)
<class '_ctypes.CField'>
```

Ideally I would like to get the field type similar to the snippet below...

```
>>> A.one.type
c_long
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `_fields_` list:

```
>>> for f,t in A._fields_:
...  a = getattr(A,f)
...  print a,a.offset,a.size,t
...
<Field type=c_long, ofs=0, size=4> 0 4 <class 'ctypes.c_long'>
<Field type=c_char, ofs=4, size=1> 4 1 <class 'ctypes.c_char'>
<Field type=c_byte, ofs=5, size=1> 5 1 <class 'ctypes.c_byte'>
```

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't appear to be supported in the ctypes API. When the `Field` repr `<Field type=c_long ..>` is created, the name is retrieved from the embedded type like this:

```
name = ((PyTypeObject *)self->proto)->tp_name;
```

For your field the member `self->proto` points to `c_long`, yet I find no place in Python 2.7's [`cfield.c`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c?revision=86833&view=markup) where you can retrieve the value of `self->proto` itself.  You may be forced either to:

1. Create your own mapping from `name` -> `type`.
2. (yuck) Parse the repr for `<Field type=X` and use `getattr(ctypes, X)` to fetch the type object.

---

Just to follow up with an example of **option (1)**, here's a class decorator which creates the type mapping for you, adding a `_typeof(cls, fld)` class method:

```
from ctypes import *

def typemap(cls):
    _types = dict((getattr(cls, t), v) for t, v in cls._fields_)
    setattr(cls, '_typeof', classmethod(lambda c, f: _types.get(f)))
    return cls

@typemap
class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("one", c_long),
                ("two", c_char),
                ("three", c_byte)]

print A._typeof(A.one), A._typeof(A.two), A._typeof(A.three)
```

Result:

```
<class 'ctypes.c_long'> <class 'ctypes.c_char'> <class 'ctypes.c_byte'>
```